# I cannot understand core dump cause of fgetc, how can I fix it?

Tags: c, matrix, segmentation-fault, malloc

I allocated matrix like this :

```
prevMatrix = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int) * arraySize[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize[0]; i++) {
        prevMatrix[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * arraySize[1]);
}
```

I checked `arraySize[]` has normal value. `arraySize[0]` means row, and `arraySize[1]` means column.

and I handed over the matrix like this :

```
void getInputMatrix(FILE* input, int column, int** matrix)

getInputMatrix(input, arraySize[1], prevMatrix);
```

and then function's body is this :

```
void getInputMatrix(FILE* input, int column, int** matrix) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, c = 0;
    while (!feof(input)) {
        if (j == column) {
            j = 0;
            i++;
        }
        c = fgetc(input);
        
        if (c != EOF && c != 32 && c != 10 && c != 13) {
            matrix[i][j] = c - 48;
            j++;
        }
    }
}
```

this is the example of matrix file:

```
1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 1 1 0
0 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1 0
1 0 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 1
```

It works very well in VS 2019, but it cause segmentation fault in Linux system(Ubuntu).

This program works well in Linux till the column is 6 or 7, but it occurs `corrupted size vs. prev_size` error or `segmentation fault`when the column overs that number.

Is it a problem of allocation? or fgetc()?
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, your first level allocation should be using the size of an `int` *pointer* rather than an `int`:

```c
int **prevMatrix = malloc(sizeof(int*) * arraySize[0]);
```

If those types are different sizes, your original code could have a problem.

And, just as an aside, you should not cast the `malloc` return value in C, it can cause subtle problems.